# Формулировка запроса SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, запрос

Есть две таблицы в одной БД group и student, задача стоит вытащить группы в которых нет студентов, в таблице student есть столбец groupID который обозначает айдишник группы, когда я пытаюсь вытянуть таким образом

```
SELECT `group`.Number FROM `group`, `student` WHERE student.GroupID <> `group`.`ID`
```

Сервер возвращает вообще все группы да еще и дублирует их (номера групп), как можно реализовать решение?

Comment: `... LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL`

Comment: @Akina А LEFT JOIN и WHERE как использовать вместе-то подзапросом?

Comment: Подзапрос? нафига он тут нужен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM `group`
LEFT JOIN student
ON `student`.`GroupID` = `group`.`ID`
WHERE `student`.`GroupID` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Number from group where ID not in (select GroupId from student group by GroupId);
```